# Set back button color

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have set all bar button items, including back buttons, with...

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

However, I want to override the back button color on one page but I cannot find a reference to a back button. All the references with the right sounding name are null.

Why are they all null? Where does the back button come from?

Comment: Please add your code. Maybe you are setting it in the wrong place. The navigation related controls will not be set in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: When will they be set? It’s not when appearing either.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without using the `appearance` proxy. Set the main window's `tintColor` property to your default color. Then in your specific view controller's `viewWillAppear` / `viewWillDisappear` set / reset the specific color:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow? {
        didSet {
            // set your default tint color
            window?.tintColor = .red
        }
    }

}

class SpecificViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .magenta
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = nil
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

}
```

Results in:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

What you should rather be doing is setting the `navigationBar.tintColor`.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = .red
```

This will apply the color to every navigation bar. So you have to set and reset it again in the view controller you want to change the color.

In `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.navigationContoller?.navigationBar.tintColor = .blue
```

In `viewWillDisappear`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```